How to turn off automatic placement in 3D slicers?
Hey guys i have a problem that is bugging me for a long time now i am making a program that will automatically place 3D objects using heuristics, the problem is that when i have my STL models shifted to the right position i can't really import it in any slicer. The main problem is the automatic placement of the slicer which rewrites the positional data stored in the .STL file Any way to turn this auto placement off so it only loads position from the file?
Thanks in advance
I tried multiple slicers, asking chat-gpt, reading documentation of the slicers, etc. But the setting to turn it off is nowhere to be found
(it doesn't matter what kind of slicer it is, if anyone has any experience please suggest any of them)

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

What exactly are you trying to do?  Are you trying to generate a STL with items automatically arranged on a build plate (maybe based on defined build coordinate parameters)?  If not, I'm not following the logic of NOT wanting to reposition the object in the slicer so that it is at a reasonable position on the build plate.

I am loading 3D objects from STL file. Then i am shifting the object to (for example) index (100, 100, 0). I Then save the object to STL file again with the shift. So when i try to plot the mesh of the shifted object in matplotlib it works correctly and shows the object shifted the way i wanted to. However i need to now upload this file to some program capable of creating G-code out of it to be used in 3D printing. When i upload the STL file (with shift), the program (Fusion360, Ultimaker Cura, PrusaSlicer etc.) always puts the object in the middle, i need to manually move it.

Why doesnt it move to the coordinates that are specified in the STL? I am sorry if its not stated correctly, english is not my mother language

The main reason why i want to use this is i am creating a bigger project that will try to reach optimal placing of 3D objects for printing. Its already doing that i just need to export these objects (including their positions found in my algorithm) to 3D printer to print them. I ideally want to do it without manualy moving them in Fusion360.

I not sure an .STL-file has any means to place items in space.
To keep a "setup" (scene, with item positions) in a slicer,
save a "project" file (e.g. in Cura).
